Calculate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}(1-e^{-t})^{n}e^{-t^2}dt}$

$$
\mbox{Calculate}\quad
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_{1/2}^{\infty}
\left(1 - {\rm e}^{-t}\right)^{n}{\rm e}^{-t^{2}}{\rm d}t
$$


Basically I don't know where to start.
I was thinking of using Tonelli Theorem but I have no idea how to calculate this sum, and neither do I know how to solve this integral.
I also tried to expand
$\left(1 - {\rm e}^{-t}\right)^{n}$ but that seems to lead
nowhere.

This is a problem from Introductory Measure Theory course so I was expecting some of those methods to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You do not need to have an infinite upper bound since, after completinf the square $$\int_a ^b  e^{t-t^2},dt=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{e} \sqrt{\pi }   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}-a\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}-b\right)\right)$$

$$
\begin{align*}
       \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^\infty (1 - e^{-t})^n e^{-t^2}dt &= \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (1 - e^{-t})^n e^{-t^2}dt
\end{align*}
$$
Recall the formula
$$
     \sum_{n = 0}^\infty q^n = \dfrac{1}{1 - q} \ \forall q, \vert q \vert < 1
$$
Since $0 < (1 - e^{-t}) < 1 \ \forall t \ge \dfrac{1}{2}$, we have
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (1 - e^{-t})^n e^{-t^2} = \dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{1 - (1 - e^{-t})} = e^{t - t^2}
$$
Thus,
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^\infty (1 - e^{-t})^n e^{-t^2}dt = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^\infty \exp(t - t^2)dt
$$
Notice that
$$
   \exp(t - t^2) = \exp\left(-\left(t - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)\exp(1/4)
$$
and
$$
    \int_{1/2}^\infty \exp\left(-\left(t - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)dt = \int_0^\infty \exp(-u^2)du = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^\infty (1 - e^{-t})^n e^{-t^2}dt = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{1/4}}{2}
$$

And, if I am correct, we can interchange summation and integration because $(1-e^{-t})^{n}e^{-t^2}$ is always positive?

@Ranko Yes, you are correct
